# Operations on formal power series in two variables.

Tags: power-series, formal-power-series

I am wondering about the operations that can be done on a formal power series in two variables. For instance, let $p\left(x,y\right)=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty}\sum _{m=0}^{\infty}c_{nm}x^ny^m$. We can obtain 
$$p_{\textrm{even}}\left(x,y\right)=\sum _{n+m\textrm{ is even}}c_{nm}x^ny^m$$
as 
$$p_{\textrm{even}}\left(x,y\right)=\frac{p\left(x,y\right)+p\left(-x,-y\right)} {2}$$
and we can make countless other operations, for instance $$p_{\textrm{translate }k,l}\left(x,y\right)=\sum _{n=k}^{\infty}\sum _{m=l}^{\infty}c_{n-k,m-l}x^ny^m$$
as 
$$p_{\textrm{translate }k,l}\left(x,y\right)=x^ky^lp\left(x,y\right)$$
Are there operations we can do to get 
$$p_{\textrm{diag}}\left(x,y\right)=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty}c_{nn}x^ny^n$$
in terms of $p\left(x,y\right)$? So far the only thing I can think of is if $c_{nm}=0$ whenever $n<m$ (we could call it "upper triangular" in analogy to a matrix) then 
$$p_{\textrm{diag}}\left(x,y\right)=\lim_{c\rightarrow 0}p\left(cx,c^{-1}y\right)$$
Is there a name for this kind of process? The links between power series operations and operations on their coefficients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Hint:** Using the *coefficient of* operator $[y^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $y^n$ of a series we can extract the diagonal from $p(x,y)$ via
>   \begin{align*}
> G(t)=[y^0]p\left(\frac{t}{y},y\right)=\sum_{n} a_{n,n}t^n
> \end{align*}

This is discussed in R.P. Stanleys *[Enumerative Combinatorics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HMUGS4S)* section 6.3. *Diagonals*.

Related information can be found in *[this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.04526.pdf)*. Interesting information about diagonalisation is also given in *[this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/104832/a-diagonal-operation-on-power-series/221089#221089)*.